# Getting the user name who executed the stored procedure in Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

Someone ran a stored procedure from his machine, and I just want to know who executed that stored procedure.

I am trying to see sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats but I'm having no luck:

```
SELECT object_id
FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id,database_id) = 'SpName'
```

Comment: That query is looking for an *object* name, not a user. You can get the current user inside the stored procedure with [CURRENT_USER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Unless you have any logged/extended events/Traces set up, it's unlikely you'll know who has previous run the SP.

Comment: oops there is no way to know who executed the sp?

Comment: @user960567 not without logging or a time machine, no. :) I *suppose* you could ask every member of staff and hope they are honest. If knowing who runs an SP is important, then I suggest implementing logging of some kind; either within the SP, or using Extended Events. It won't help you with past events but it'll tell you in the future.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135078/how-to-get-history-of-queries-executed-with-username-in-sql what about this?

Comment: It looks like the scenario here is that someone executed a stored procedure at a wrong moment or at the wrong database, messing up some valuable data. Now you want to find out who did this, in order to blame that person. But if this is the case, you don't have a managerial problem, you have an operational problem. Why did this person have the permissions to execute that stored procedure on that database in the first place? Check your employees' permissions and configure them accordingly.

Comment: This is just a technical question :). At least there should be a way. Off course, it's not critical from our side and no blames but we should wanna keep logs.

Comment: @user960567 That means you need to know the session ID and/or user id. you could use the query without the `WHERE`, but you'll be looking through a hay stack. Traces (which I recommend far less than an XEvent or In house logged) can't go back in time either; so the best thing you can really do at this stage is set things up now, so you don't have this problem in the future.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find out by using objecy_id :)

Comment: There is "a way", if you set it up. If you haven't, then there isn't. For example, there is a way to know where a car has been driving, at what speeds, etc; it's called a Black Box. The Black Box, however, can't tell you what the car did **before** it was installed. The same logic applies here.

Comment: Thanks larnu. For now using dba link above and adding object_id fixed my issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135078/how-to-get-history-of-queries-executed-with-username-in-sql and updated with my logic and its worked for me

```
USE master
go
SELECT top 10 sdest.DatabaseName 
    ,sdes.session_id
    ,sdes.[host_name]
    ,sdes.[program_name]
    ,sdes.client_interface_name
    ,sdes.login_name
    ,sdes.login_time
    ,sdes.nt_domain
    ,sdes.nt_user_name
    ,sdec.client_net_address
    ,sdec.local_net_address
    ,sdest.ObjName
    ,sdest.Query
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions AS sdes
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_connections AS sdec ON sdec.session_id = sdes.session_id
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT db_name(dbid) AS DatabaseName
        ,object_id(objectid) AS ObjName
        ,ISNULL((
                SELECT TEXT AS [processing-instruction(definition)]
                FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sdec.most_recent_sql_handle)
                FOR XML PATH('')
                    ,TYPE
                ), '') AS Query

    FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sdec.most_recent_sql_handle) WHERE OBJECT_NAME(objectid,dbid)='MySp' 
    ) sdest
where sdes.session_id <> @@SPID  
--and sdes.nt_user_name = '' -- Put the username here !
ORDER BY sdec.session_id
```

Comment: It could work if the session still exists and if the procedure execution was the last which was done by the session